# what's wrong with this graphql schema ,the server is starting but the localhost is not loading?

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I'm creating a GraphQL Server using Node JS.
The server is running but the http://localhost:3000/graphql is not responding.

I have created object `UserType` , `CabType` and `BookingType` of `GraphQLObjectType` as follows:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: () => ({
        uid: { type: GraphQLString },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        age: { type: GraphQLString },
        bookings: {
            type: BookingType,
            resolve(parent, args) {
                // code getting bookings of that user
            }
        }
    })
});
 

const CabType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Cab',
    fields: () => ({
        cid: { type: GraphQLString },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        age: { type: GraphQLInt }
    })

});


const BookingType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Booking',
    fields: () => ({
        bid: { type: GraphQLString },
        uid: { type: GraphQLString },
        cid: { type: GraphQLString },
        from: { type: GraphQLString },
        to: { type: GraphQLInt }
    })

});
```

Here `RootQuery` and `RootMutation` are alos `GraphQLObjectType` contains `fields` like `user` ,`cab` and `booking`

```
    const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'RootQueryType',
        fields: {
            user: {
                type: UserType,
                args: {
                    uid: { type: GraphQLString }
                },
                resolve(parent, args) {
                    //code to get user data from db
                }
            },
    
            Cab: {
                type: CabType,
                args: {
                    cid: { type: GraphQLString }
                },
                resolve(parent, args) {
    
                    //code for getting all the cabs
    
                }
    
            },
    
            Booking: {
                type: BookingType,
                args: {
                    uid: { type: GraphQLString }
                },
                resolve(parent, args) {
    
                    //code for getting all the bookings by user with id
    
                }
            }
        }
    
    });
    
    
    
    
    
    const RootMutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    
        name: 'Mutation',
        fields: {
            addUser: {
                type: UserType,
                args: {
                    name: { type: GraphQLString },
                    email: { type: GraphQLString },
                },
    
                resolve(parent, args) {
    
                    let user = new user({
                        name: args.name,
                        email: args.email
                    });
    
                    return user.create();
                    //add user code db
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Here the graphql schema `GraphQLScema` is exported to the server file,the server is starting but localhost is not responding to the `graphql` route.

```
    module.exports = new GraphQLSchema( {
        query: RootQuery,
        mutation: RootMutation
    });
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. Because of improper indentation, it's getting messed up. Also, try to debug the code-snippet yourself as it includes a lot of lines, and find the part which is causing the problem.

Comment: The motive behind posting a question is to make other people understand the problem, author's intent, and his/her findings, which I think are lagging in this question. I can refer to the URL that you posted but that's not the point. I tried editing your question but couldn't because it requires a minimum no. of characters to be changed, and in order to do so, I'd have to add the description myself, which is not right. Please edit your question yourself so that others could also understand it. Refer to the panel at the right side when you're editing, it'd help you.

Comment: Please have a look ,I have indented the code . .